# Return the indexes of a sub-array in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use Python with `numpy`.

I have a numpy array `may_a`:

```
may_a = numpy.array([False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False])
```

I have a numpy array `may_b`:

```
may_b = numpy.array([False,True,True,False])
```

I need to find array `may_b` in array `may_a`.

In the output I need to get indexes of occurrences.

```
out_index=[2,7]
```

Can someone please suggest, **how do I get `out_index`?**

Comment: Did you mean `out_index=[2,6]` ?

Comment: @Konfle Dolex, out_index=[2,7]

Comment: @Olga Ah. I misread your question.

Comment: @Robin, no, it is search of the optimum decision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** The following code does allow to perform a convolution based check of equality. It maps `True` to `1` and `False` to `-1`. It also reverses `b`, which is needed for it to work properly:

```
def search(a, b) :
    return np.where(np.round(fftconvolve(a * 2 - 1, (b * 2 - 1)[::-1],
                                         mode='valid') - len(b)) == 0)[0]
```

I have checked that it gives the same output as the `as_strided` method for a variety of random inputs, which it does. I have also timed both approached, and convolution only starts paying off with largish search tokens of around 256 items.

---

It seems like a little overkill, but with boolean data you can use (abuse?) convolution:

```
In [8]: np.where(np.convolve(may_a, may_b.astype(int),
   ...:                      mode='valid') == may_b.sum())[0]
Out[8]: array([2, 7])
```

For larger datasets it may be faster to go with `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`:

```
In [13]: np.where(scipy.signal.fftconvolve(may_a, may_b,
   ....:                                   mode='valid') == may_b.sum())[0]
Out[13]: array([2, 7])
```

You have to be careful though, because the output now is floating point, and rounding may spoil the equality check:

```
In [14]: scipy.signal.fftconvolve(may_a, may_b, mode='valid')
Out[14]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.])
```

So you may be better off with something along the lines of:

```
In [15]: np.where(np.round(scipy.signal.fftconvolve(may_a, may_b, mode='valid') -
   ....:                   may_b.sum()) == 0)[0]
Out[15]: array([2, 7])
```

Comment: With This convolution you'll match anything that is `[*, True, True, *]` where `*` is a wildcard.

Comment: @BiRico Oops, you are absolutely right! There may be a chance to salvage the method, by mapping the `True`'s and the `False`'s to some integer value, possibly `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: @Jaime `>>> may_a = np.array([True,True,True,True])
>>> out_ind = np.where(np.convolve(may_a, may_b.astype(int),mode='valid') == may_b.sum())[0]
>>> out_ind              -> array([0])`  it is incorrect(

Comment: @Olga Yes, that's what BiRico was saying. But the method in my edit at the top of the answer works fine: `out_ind = np.where(np.convolve(may_a * 2 - 1, (may_b * 2 - 1)[::-1], mode='valid') == len(may_b))`

Comment: @Jaime What if array is 2-dimension? may_a= np.array([[0,1,2],[2,3,1],[3,4,5],[3,3,3]]); may_b = np.array([[3,3,3],[2,3,1]]); this method failed

Answer (score 5):

A much cooler approach, which may not perform a well, but which works for any dtype, is to use `as_strided`:

```
In [2]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [3]: may_a = numpy.array([False, True, False, True, True, False,
   ...:                      True, False, True, True, False])

In [4]: may_b = numpy.array([False,True,True,False])

In [5]: a = len(may_a)

In [6]: b = len(may_b)

In [7]: a_view = as_strided(may_a, shape=(a - b + 1, b),
   ...:                     strides=(may_a.dtype.itemsize,) * 2)

In [8]: a_view
Out[8]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [9]: numpy.where(numpy.all(a_view == may_b, axis=1))[0]
Out[9]: array([2, 7])
```

You have to be careful though, because even though `a_view` is a view of `may_a`'s data, when comparing it with `may_b` a temporary array of `(a - b + 1) * b` is created, which may be a problem with large `a`s and `b`s.

Comment: Maybe you appreciate pointing out small things... Not using `.itemsize` but `.strides[0]` is a bit less prone to failure, in case the array was sliced previously.

Answer (score 3):

This looks very similar to a [string search problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms). If you want to avoid implementing one these string search algorithms, you could abuse pythons built in string search, which is very fast, by doing something like:

```
# I've added [True, True, True] at the end.
may_a = numpy.array([False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True])
may_b = numpy.array([False,True,True,False])

may_a_str = may_a.tostring()
may_b_str = may_b.tostring()

idx = may_a_str.find(may_b_str)
out_index = []
while idx >= 0:
    out_index.append(idx)
    idx = may_a_str.find(may_b_str, idx+1)
```

This should work fine for boolean arrays. If you want to use this approach for another array type, you'll need to make sure the strides of the two arrays match and divide out_index by that stride.

You could also use the [regular expression module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead of the loop to do the string search.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work with other that boolean data:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False])

In [3]: b = np.array([False,True,True,False])

In [4]: def get_indices(a, b):
   ...:     window = len(b)
   ...:     shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
   ...:     strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
   ...:     w = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
   ...:     return np.where(np.all(np.equal(w,b),1) == True)[0]

In [5]: get_indices(a,b)
Out[5]: array([2, 7])
```

Comment: I changed an array `a`. `>>> a=np.array([False,False])    >>> b=np.array([False,True,True,False])  >>> get_indices(a,b)`  `>>> Out: ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`

Comment: @Olga -- Yes, `shape` will be `(-1, 4)`, you can add `if len(a) < len(b): return np.array([])` to prevent that as in that case `b` cannot possibly be a subarray of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether numpy provide a function for that. If it does not, here is a solution:

```
import numpy

def searchListIndexs(array, target):
    ret = []
    iLimit = len(array)-len(target)+1
    jLimit = len(target)
    for i in range(iLimit):
        for j in range(jLimit):
            if array[i+j] != target[j]:
                break
        else:
            ret.append(i)
    return ret


may_a = numpy.array([False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False])
may_b = numpy.array([False,True,True,False])
out_index = searchListIndexs(may_a, may_b)
print out_index #If you are using Python 3, then use print(out_index) instead.
```

Comment: Yep. :( This is a limitation of this approach.

Comment: BTW, I guess that these is no faster algorithm than this. I *guess* it is necessary to iterate through the entire array because no sorting is possible in this case.